# $\lambda$ charge, $\mu$ measure, $\lambda \bot \mu$ implies $\lambda^{+},\lambda^{-},|\lambda|\, \bot\, \mu$

Tags: measure-theory, singular-measures

Let $\lambda$ a charge and $\mu$ a measure in $(X,\mathcal{X})$, with $\lambda\,\bot\,\mu $. So, $\exists A,B\in\mathcal{X}$ such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $X=A\cup B$ and $\lambda(A)=\mu(B)=0.$

I'm trying to prove that $\lambda^{+}\bot\,\mu $.

Let $X=P\cup N$ the Hahn's decomposition of $X$ with respect with $\lambda$. I draw a picture to help me to find sets $C,D$ that leads me to $\lambda^{+}\bot\,\mu$.[image]
By the picture, I taught in $C=B\cap N,D=A\cup(B\cap P)$. Here, $\mu(D)=\mu(B\cap N)\leq \mu (B)=0\implies \mu(D)=0,$ but I can't prove that $\lambda(C)=0$. What can I do?

Comment: Let $\mathcal X_B := \{C\cap B : C\in\mathcal X\}$ and $\lambda_B(D) := \lambda(D)$ for $D\in\mathcal X_B$. Then you find a Hahn decomposition $(P_B,N_B)$ of $B$ and $\lambda_B = \lambda_B^+-\lambda_B^-$. Now, show that $(P_B\cup A,N_B)$ is a Hahn decomposition of $X$ and $\lambda^\pm(C) := \lambda_B^\pm(C\cap B)$ is the corresponding Jordan decomposition. Then, of course, $\lambda^+\perp\mu$.

Comment: Why this is really a Hahn's decomposition?
Let $C\in\mathcal{X}$. So $\lambda((P_{B}\cup A)\cap C)=\lambda((P_{B}\cap C)\cup(A\cap C))=\lambda(P_{B}\cap C)+\lambda(A\cap C)$. We have $\lambda(P_{B}\cap C)\geq 0$, but why  we cannot say anything about $\lambda (A\cap C)$.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow thought that $\lambda$ is supposed to be zero on every subset of $A$.

Comment: You have the definition of $\lambda\perp\mu$ wrong! Your $\lambda(A)=0$ should be $|\lambda|(A)=0$ (which is the same as $\lambda(E)=0$ for all $E\subset A$, explaining amsmath's confusion.)

Comment: Maybe you're confused by the notation. The $|\lambda|(A)$ you see in the book is not the same as $|\lambda(A)|$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work. Consider $X =\{a,b,c,d\}$ and set $A = \{a\}$, $B = \{b\}$, $C = \{c\}$, and $D = \{d\}$. Define measures $\lambda^\pm$ and $\mu$ by

$\mu(A)=\mu(B)=1$, $\mu(C) = \mu(D) = 0$,

$\lambda^-(B) = \lambda^-(C) = \lambda^-(D) = 0$, and $\lambda^-(A) = 1$,

$\lambda^+(B) = \lambda^+(C) = \lambda^+(D) = 1$, and $\lambda^+(A) = 0$,

as well as $\lambda = \lambda^+-\lambda^-$. Then $\lambda(A\cup B) = 0$ and $\mu(C\cup D) = 0$. However, you will not find any set $E$ such that $\lambda^+(E) = 0$ and $\mu(X\setminus E) = 0$ because the first condition is only satisfied for $E = A$ and $E=\emptyset$, but $\mu(X\setminus A) = 1$ and $\mu(X\setminus\emptyset) = 2$.

Comment: So this is a counterexample to my question? I mean, not necessarily $\lambda^{+}\bot \mu$ when $\lambda\bot\mu$

Comment: You got it, mate. ;-)

Comment: My book don't asks me if this is right, it asks me to prove it. Well, MSE wins again.

Comment: Please upvote and check my answer if you are content with it. Thanks.